# フォロー機能を実装しようとしたらrails sできない

Tags: ruby-on-rails

relationshipフォロー、フォロワー機能を記述してrails s しようとしたらサーバーが立ち上がらなくなりました。　どこかの引数が間違っているみたいなのですがどこを直して良いかわかりません。

```
rails s
=> Booting Puma
=> Rails 6.1.7 application starting in development 
=> Run `bin/rails server --help` for more startup options
Exiting
/home/ec2-user/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.1.2/gems/activesupport-6.1.7/lib/active_support/core_ext/hash/keys.rb:52:in `block in assert_valid_keys': Unknown key: :souce. Valid keys are: :class_name, :anonymous_class, :primary_key, :foreign_key, :dependent, :validate, :inverse_of, :strict_loading, :autosave, :before_add, :after_add, :before_remove, :after_remove, :extend, :counter_cache, :join_table, :index_errors, :ensuring_owner_was, :through, :source, :source_type (ArgumentError)
```

以下、該当していそうなコードです。初学者なので見づらい部分があると思いますが
よろしくお願いします。

relationships.controller

```
class RelationshipsController < ApplicationController

  def create
    @user = User.find(params[:user_id])
    current_user.follow(params[:user_id])
    redirect_to request.referer
  end

  def destroy
    current_user.unfollow(params[:user_id])
    redirect_to request.referer
  end

  
  def followings
    user = User.find(params[:user_id])
    @users = user.followings
  end
 
 def followers
   user = User.find(params[:user_id])
   @users = user.followers
 end
end
```

relationship.rb

```
class Relationship < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :follower, class_name: "User"
  belongs_to :followed, class_name: "User"
end
```

user.rb

```
has_many :relationships, class_name: "Relationship", foreign_key: 
  "follower_id", dependent: :destroy
has_many :reverse_of_relationships, class_name: "Relationship", 
  foreign_key: "followed_id", dependent: :destroy
has_many :followings, through: :relationships, souce: :followed
  has_many:followers,through::reverse_of_relationships,souce::follower

def follow(user_id)
  relationships.create(followed_id: user_id)
  end

  def unfollow(user_id)
  relationships.find_by(followed_id: user_id).destroy
  end
  
  def following?(user)
  followings.include?(user)
  end
end
```

routes.rb

```
 resources :users do
    resource :relationships, only: [:create, :destroy]
    get 'folloeings' => 'relationships#followings', as: 'followings'
    get 'followers' => 'relationships#followers' , as: 'followers'
  end
```

migration file

```
class CreateRelationships < ActiveRecord::Migration[6.1]
  def change
    create_table :relationships do |t|
      t.integer :follower_id
      t.integer :followed_id
      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 3):

まずはエラーメッセージをよく読んでください。`Unknown key: :souce.`と書かれていますね。その後の`Valid keys are: ...`に妥当なキーの一覧がありますが、`:souce`はありません。なので、そんなキーは知らないと言うことでエラーになったと言うことです。妥当なキーには`:source`があるので、スペルミスだと思われます。

ということで、ソースコード全体から`souce`と書いているところを検索してください。質問に上げたコードには含まれてないようです。ここで注意が一つですが、`:souce`ではなく`souce`と`:`無しで検索してください。文字列やメソッド名になっている事もあるからです。見つけたら`source`と修正してみてください。これでたぶん、なおると思います。

---

エラーには何が間違っているかのヒントが書いています。まずは意味を理解して(英語を読んで)、ヒントになりそうな名称(メッソド名とか、クラスメイトか、シンボルとか)を検索するなど、だいたい解決できるものです。

Comment: ご指摘いただいたsouceが書いてあるところを修正したところ無事解決しました。エラーを読み解くアドバイスもしていただきありがとうございました。アドバイスを生かして頑張ってエラー解決にいかしていきます。